# Can't update the content of angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a simple cms with angularjs but I have a problem with the directives.

I can't update the content of a directive. I don't receive any error, but the content is not updated.

Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
var postApp = angular.module('adminApp', [
  'ngRoute', 'angular-ladda'
]);

postApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/posts', {
            templateUrl: '/ngpartials/admin/blog/index.html',
            controller: 'PostListCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/posts'
        });
    }
]);

postApp.controller('PostListCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.showLoading = false;

    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.name = 'Mike';
});

postApp.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            name: "="
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h3>Hello World!!: {{ name }}</h3>'
    };
});
```

**template:**

```
<div ng-controller="PostListCtrl" class="ui grid container">

    <h1 class="ui header"><a href="#/posts/">Posts</a></h1>

    <hello-world></hello-world>

    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

**Result:**

Hello World!!:

Comment: You had bad design of having same controller nested for no reason..please don't do that..look at mine answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<hello-world name="name"></hello-world>
```

Directive has isolated scope so it does not inherit data from controller's scope. You shall pass information from current scope to directive's isolated scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the name to the directive inside the view:

```
<hello-world name="name"></hello-world>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st problem is your controller is creating its instance twice, `body` has its `ng-controller` and `$routerProvider` has is loading other instance of `PostListCtrl` controller.

> Having such kind of approach, creating controller instance twice
>   wouldn't make sense in design point of view.

So suppose when you are updating `name` scope value of `ng-view` loaded template which is `/ngpartials/admin/blog/index.html` will not updated `helloWorld` directive `name`, as its placed outside & it getting value of `name` variable from controller assigned to `body` tag.

Then I'll say that move your directive to `/ngpartials/admin/blog/index.html` content like also pass the value of name to directive element.

```
<hello-world name="name"></hello-world>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your custom directive code.

```
postApp.directive('helloWorld', function() {

    return {
        scope: {
            name: "="
        },
        scope:true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h3>Hello World!!: {{ name }}</h3>'
    };
});
```

I am also attaching here JsFiddle link :- http://jsfiddle.net/kpsingh/U3pVM/22839/